# ReSharper I18n features don't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internationalization, resharper

I have an Asp MVC app that was developed with no I18N in mind. Now I need to move all hardcoded strings from Razor views and from C# code to a resource file.

I thought I can use ReShaper to help me with that as described here: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/internationalization.html#Move_Strings_to_Resource_Files

However, it doesn't highlight/underline hardcoded strings in any of my project files (views, classes, ...).

Do I need to enable this somehow? I'm running VS2015 + ReSharper9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a resource file in your project before any features show up. Go to the project properties, select the resources tab, and click on the link to create a file.